# React: Why isn't my context value updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-context

I'm playing with React Context API. I created a simple component:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext } from 'react';

const MyContext = createContext(1);

const MyComponent = () => (
    <>
        <p>{useContext(MyContext)}</p>
        <MyContext.Provider value={2}>
            <p>{useContext(MyContext)}</p>
        </MyContext.Provider>
    </>
);

export default MyComponent;
```

I'm getting two `<p>1</p>`. Why isn't the second context updated with `2`? Am I using `useContext()` incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use a separate Component to get Context to work.

I've filed a bug about this; see https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18629

Simply split the code using the Context into a different Component.

```
const Inner = () => (
    <p>{useContext(MyContext)}</p>
);

const MyComponent = () => (
    <>
        <p>{useContext(MyContext)}</p>
        <MyContext.Provider value={2}>
            <Inner />
        </MyContext.Provider>
    </>
);
```

That should fix it.

Comment: Thanks! I used Context in the past and didn't have any problems. I'm now experimenting to understand it better and I was surprised my example didn't work as expected. I agree it seems to be a bug!

Comment: I felt the same way. Wasted a ton of time trying to figure out why. But if Our Lord and Savior Dan Abramov does not think it is a bug, then it is not. (Feel free, however, to pressure Dan by adding a +1 to the issue, or to link this SO question there)

Comment: Well, there are more confusing things in React, so I guess that's by design :D

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to render another component inside the context provider to get the value of 2. As `useContext`'s documentation states:

> Accepts a context object (the value returned from React.createContext) and returns the current context value for that context. The current context value is determined by the value prop of the nearest <MyContext.Provider> **above the calling component in the tree**.

Emphasis added. The important point is that it doesn't matter where you call `useContext` inside the component - what matters is where that component where it's called in is located in the tree.

```
import React, { createContext, useContext } from "react";

const MyContext = createContext(1);

const ChildComponent = () => (
  <p>{useContext(MyContext)}</p>
)

const MyComponent = () => (
  <>
      <p>{useContext(MyContext)}</p>
      <MyContext.Provider value={2}>
        <ChildComponent/>
      </MyContext.Provider>
  </>
);

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Surprised I got the accept here, liked your quote from the documentation.